# How to resolve a path containing a star character in Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, bash

I want to access an Android device over MTP using Nodejs running on Linux.

The Android device is mounted at `/run/user/1000/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C010%5D` and can be treated as a regular file system thanks to MTP.

Now the part after `mtp:host=` (`%5Busb%3A002%2C010%5D` in this case) always depends on the physical USB port on which the Android device is connected.

A way to ensure we always get the right path to the file system is to use something like

```
$ cd /run/user/1000/gvfs/mtp*
```

This works well in `bash` and will indeed resolve into

```
~$ cd /run/user/1000/gvfs/mtp*
/run/user/1000/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C010%5D$
```

but I can't seem to resolve the correct path in Nodejs either using `path.resolve` or `path.normalize`. Even the POSIX implementations of `path` (`path.posix`) don't help.

**Do you know a way to resolve a path containing a wildcard in Nodejs?**

NB: of course I assume here that only one MTP device is plugged at a time.

Answer (score 2):

As you're using nodejs I'd suggest looking at [glob](https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob)